# Is there a way to hide the csrf label while looping through form using Flask and Flask-WTForms?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have very simple contact form and I would like to hide the label somehow so that it doesn't show `Csrf Token`. I am using Flask and Flask-WTForms and am rendering the form like this:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field.label }}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

So basically this shows my inputs correctly and the csrf oen is hidden but the label isn't hidden? Should I get over it and implicitly say `form.field_name` instead of looping through the form or is there a way to handle this "corner case".

I was thinking about doing a logical check in either the for loop declaration or the label declaration but so far I haven't found anything in the documentation that has worked.

Thanks

EDIT: I have "fixed" the problem by doing this but it feels kinda dirty and hacky which I don't like I am still open to a better solution:

```
{% if not loop.first %}
    {{ field.label }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you want a more general solution that works for all hidden fields instead of just the CSRF token:

```
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
{% for field in form if field.widget.input_type != 'hidden' %}
  {{ field.label }}
  {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

`form.hidden_tag()` is supplied by Flask-WTF.

Comment: so you mean that `{{ form.csrf_token }}` is would automatically be used if just use `form.hidden_tag()`?

Comment: your solution works, but I can not figure out how to render field errors. form.errors.field do not work

Comment: @mickey06: csrf field is inserted via hidden_tag()

Answer (score 9):

Just to add to JD's excellent answer...

For those stumbling across this question: **You can avoid losing the (csrf) hidden field** (and thus protection) by adding the condition "if field.widget.input_type!='hidden' " specifically to the label instead of to the form iterator.

i.e.:

**not**

```
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
{% for field in form if field.widget.input_type != 'hidden' %}
      {{ field.label }}
{{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

**but**

```
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
{% for field in form %}
  {% if field.widget.input_type != 'hidden' %} {{ field.label }} {% endif %}
  {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: No need to do this, because {{ form.hidden_tag() }} secure the protection itself, since it renders the hidden fields before the for loop.

Answer (score 8):

I think this should work too:

```
{% for field in form if field.id != 'csrf_token' %}
    {{ field.label }}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Better use `short_name` - otherwise it'll break if the form has a prefix.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the way to do it like this:

```
{% if field.id != 'csrf_token' %}
```

I believe this to be less hacky. I found this from modifying the example [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/switching/#conditions) in the docs.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out shortly afterward: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10764703/1165441.

Answer (score 1):

I made a macro recently to submit forms through ajax in order to not reload the webpage and send it to the api directly.

```
{% macro render_fields3(form, form_name, method) %}
<form class="ajax" name={{ form_name }} method={{ method }}>
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
{% for field in form if field.widget.input_type != 'hidden' %}
    <dt>{{ field.label }}
    <dd>{{field(id=field.name + method)|safe}}
    {% if field.errors %}
      <ul class=errors>
      {% for error in field.errors %}
        <li>{{ error }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% endif %}
    </dd>
  {% endfor %}

</form>
{% endmacro %}
```