# Render field errors in for loop with Flask-WTF

Tags: python, validation, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I would like to iterate over form's fields in a template and display fields with errors like this:

```
 {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {% for field in form if field.widget.input_type != 'hidden' %}
    {%  if form.errors.field %}
  <div class="has-error">  {{ field.label }}  {{ field(size=80, class_='form-control') }}</div>
    <span style="color: red;">{{ form.errors.field.0 }}</span>
    {% else %}
        {{ field.label }}  {{ field(size=80, class_='form-control') }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

But that doesn't work for some reason- the form renders but the errors are not displayed.

I've already checked solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463035/wtforms-getting-the-errors),  [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427092/sorting-wtforms-form-errors-dict),  [and also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763139/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-csrf-label-while-looping-through-form-using-flask-and) and none of those have helped.

Could someone please advise how to fix my form to correctly render the errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in using `form.errors.field`. This would only be accurate in jinja if you had a field named `field` and not for any other names.

Fortunately, you're already iterating fields, and every field has a `.errors` property so the shortest solution is to simply use that property

Your code should look something like:

```
 {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
 {% for field in form if field.widget.input_type != 'hidden' %}
   {% if field.errors %}
     <div class="has-error">  {{ field.label }}  {{ field(size=80, class_='form-control') }}</div>
     <span style="color: red;">{% for error in field.errors %}{{ error }}{% if not loop.last %}<br />{% endif %}{% endfor %}</span>
   {% else %}
      {{ field.label }}  {{ field(size=80, class_='form-control') }}
   {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```